# What did Luke know about his father?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, anakin-skywalker

What exactly does Luke know about his father?

In the movies he sees Vader kill Obi-wan, and then learns that he is his father. But does he know more about Anakin's past, like the fact that he was a slave, and the Jedi did little to help his mother which pushed him down the path to the dark side? Does he find out that Obi-wan hacked off his limbs and left him burning by a lava lake to die?

It seems like he doesn't know a lot of this history, especially since he begins trying to rebuild the Jedi order and seems to have great respect for them, despite what happened to his father and the galaxy as a result of their actions in the past.

Comment: Well he'd of had Ghost Kenobi to fill him in on the truth, from a certain point of view.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie yeah, he wasn't exactly forthcoming about that... Yoda too, e.g. in Last Jedi he doesn't mention the fact that he seems to have realized that the Jedi Order sucked and those old ideas should be abandoned, in fact if anything he implies that it's Luke's fault for not doing a better job of starting it up again.

Comment: Probably should have been talking to Qui Gin’s Force ghost instead......he saw through all the stupidity the Jedi Order possessed, and saw things even Yoda missed.

Comment: What does Luke know ***when***? At the start of the original trilogy he knows almost nothing. By the end he knows quite a lot. By the time The Force Awakens rolls around he knows even more.

Comment: Well, he learned a lot about his Dad after giving his Dad a hand...

Comment: Wait, are you blaming Obi-Wan for the Empire?

Comment: R2-D2 knows _everything_, assuming he's willing to talk and Luke knows to ask.

Comment: I think user's just saying that Darth Vader had some good points, and we shouldn't buy into the false mainstream Jedi narrative and dismiss him out of hand like a bunch of snowflakes just because he _very occasionally_ murdered groups of children.

Comment: To partially answer the question, in _Return of the Jedi_ he learns that he kinda looked better with the helmet on tbh.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone could impart information about Anakin to Luke (aside from Obi-Wan), Owen Lars (Uncle Owen) could.  Owen knew a fair bit, but his self-imposed role was to protect Luke as much as he possibly could from Jedi and the Imperials, so didn't disclose details of Anakin:

> **Owen:** "I told you, I'm not gonna let you warp the boy like you did his father. You brought him to me to protect, and that's what I'm doing. Protecting him from you."
> **Obi-Wan:** "I'm not asking to train the boy. You've made yourself quite clear on that matter. But Luke has potential to be something…truly remarkable. Just as his father was, before he—"
> **Owen:** "Before you got him killed! Haven't you murdered enough Skywalkers already, Kenobi?"
> ―Lars and Obi-Wan Kenobi[[src](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015)_15)]

And later:

> Years later, when Skywalker was twelve years old,[[19](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_Lars#cite_note-Complete_Visual_New-19)] Beru compared Skywalker to his father after Lars noted he was proud of his nephew's hard work. Refusing to discuss Anakin any further, Lars told Beru that his nephew was like a son to him. Not wanting Skywalker to experience war in his lifetime, he admitted he would not let him join the Imperial Academy. [[src](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_Lars#Raising_Luke_Skywalker)]

Further background on Owen Lars and Luke's early life with his aunt and uncle - [Star Wars Fandom - Owen Lars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Owen_Lars)

Comment: Ok, so he didn't find out from Lars when he was living with him.  But that doesn't rule out other sources mentioned in comments (force ghosts, droids), or other possible sources.

Comment: Although this tells us about Owen Lars as a potential source of information, it doesn't really answer the question about how much Luke knew about his father.

Comment: My answer only really seeks to address the time before Luke’s father revealed himself to Luke. I felt that Darth Vader was so well known to both the Republic and Empire that Luke would soon have learnt everything he needed to know about Vader. Being so protected and isolated before that point, I feel that Lars was the only reliable source of information.

Answer (score 4):

In the Disney+ TV series, [*The Book of Boba Fett*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Book_of_Boba_Fett), "Chapter 6: From the Desert Comes a Stranger", it is revealed that

> Luke Skywalker has met, and maintains a friendly relationship with [Ahsoka Tano](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano), Anakin's former Padwan learner. As a result, it is probable that he now has significant knowledge of what Anakin was like as a Jedi, from someone who knew him for years in that capacity, and is apparently willing to share information.
>
>  There is no indication in the episode, but I imagine it is also likely that she spilled the beans about R2-D2.

Comment: Perhaps. I get the feeling that Ahsoka doesn't share too much information about some topics, and Jedi are well known to be less than forthcoming.

Comment: Looking back the question and the choice he gave Grogon in that episode, I'd say there is no way he can have any understanding of what drove his father to the dark side. He's just repeating the same mistakes.